# Filtering SQL rows based on certain alphabets combination

Tags: sql-server, filter, where-clause

I have a column that store user input text field from a frontend website. User can input any kind of text in it, but they will also put in a specific alphabets combination to represent a job type - for example 'dri'. As an example:

```
Row 1: P49384; Open vehicle bonnet-BO-dri 22/10
Row 2: P93818; Vehicle exhaust-BO 10/20
Row 3: P1933; battery dri-pu-103/2
Row 4: P3193; screwdriver-pu 423
Row 5: X939; seats bo
Row 6: P9381-vehicle-pu-bo dri
```

In this case, I will like to filter only rows that contain `dri`. From the example, you can see the text can be in any order (user behaviour, they will key whatever they like without following any kind of format). But the constant is that for a particular job type, they will put in `dri`.

I know that I can simply use `LIKE` in SQL Server to get these rows. Unfortunately, row 4 is included inside when I use this operator. This is because screwdriver contains `dri`.

Is there any way in SQL Server I can do to strictly only obtain rows that has `dri` job type, while excluding words like screwdriver?

I tried to use `PATINDEX` but it failed too - `PATINDEX('%[d][r][i]%', column) > 0`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you need to fix the design, if I am honest.

Comment: It also looks like you aren't using a consistent delimiter. For example, rows 1-5 all have a value followed by a semi colon (`;`), but row 6 does not. Row 5 doesn't have  a hyphen so is `'seats bo'` one value, not two? If twot, then is `'Vehicle exhaust'` also 2 values? Honestly, the data is a mess; you are probably going to have to have someone actually review and correct all the data as part of the normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is the problem here. Unfortunately even for denormalised data it doesn't appear to have a reliable/defined format, making parsing your data in a language like T-SQL next to impossible. What problems are there? Based on the [original sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75055624/1), at a glance the following problems exist:

- The first data value's delimiter isn't consistent. Rows 1-5 use a semicolon (`;`), but row 6 uses a hyphen (`-`)
- The *last* data value's delimiter isn't consistent. Row 1, 2 & 4 use a space ( ), but row 3 uses a hyphen (`-`).
- Internal data doesn't use a consistent delimiter. For example:

  - Row 1 has a the value `Open vehicle bonnet-BO-dri`, which appears to be the values `Open vehicle bonnet`, `BO` and `dri`; so the hyphen(`-`) is the delimiter.
  - Row 5 has `seats bo`, which appears to be the values `seats` and `bo`, so uses a space ( ) as a delimiter.
  - The fact that row 6 has `vehicle` as its own value (`vehicle-pu-bo-dri`), however, implies that `Open vehicle bonnet` and `Vehicle Exhaust` (on rows 1 and 2 respectively) *could* actually be the values `Open`, `vehicle`, & `bonnet` and `Vehicle` & `Exhaust` respectively.

Honestly, the solution is to fix your design. As such, your tables should likely look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Job (JobID varchar(6) CONSTRAINT PK_JobID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED, --NONCLUSTERED Because it's not always ascending
                      YourNumericalLikeValue varchar(5) NULL); --Obviously use a better name

CREATE TABLE dbo.JobTypeCompleted(JobTypeID int IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_JobTypeID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                                  JobID varchar(6) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_JobType_Job FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Job (JobID),
                                  JobType varchar(30) NOT NULL); --Must likely this'll actually be a foreign key to an actual job type table

GO
```

Then, for a couple of your rows, the data would be inserted like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Job (JobID, YourNumericalLikeValue)
VALUES('P49384','22/10'),
      ('P9381',NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.JobTypeCompleted(JobID,JobType)
VALUES('P49384','Open vehicle bonnet'),
      ('P49384','BO'),
      ('P49384','dri'),
      ('P9381','vehicle'),
      ('P9381','pu'),
      ('P9381','bo'),
      ('P9381','dri');
```

Then you can *easily* get the jobs you want with a simple query:

```sql
SELECT J.JobID,
       J.YourNumericalLikeValue
FROM dbo.Job J
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.JobTypeCompleted JTC
              WHERE JTC.JobID = J.JobID
                AND JTC.JobType = 'dri');
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I understand that fixing the design will solve the problem, but unfortunately I do not have a control to this legacy system hence I can't do the re-designing.

Comment: Then you at least need usable denormalised data; you can't work with data that bad. *Any* assumptions you make will likely be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Larnu. Actually if I only want to extract rows with `dri` (ignoring all those pu, bo and what not), is it still possible with SQL? The main thing is to ensure words like `screwdriver` will not be inside the filter.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, @SunnyBoiz . Fix the design. With the data as you have it? No, not really, it's a mess and unreliable. It has no defined denormalised format, let alone normalised format. If you won't fix the design, you need to at least fix the data to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I will have to convince my upper management to do something about it. I will mark your answer as correct since it is the correct way to approach such issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply like operator in your query as column_name like '%-dri'. It means find out records that end with "-dri"

Comment: Hi, thanks. Forget to show an example where not all the time you will see `-dri`. `dri` can appear anytime before `-` or after, or none.

Comment: so you can simply add column_name like '%dri'. It means it will check only those records which end with "dri'
If you can add column_name like '%_dri'. It will not specifically check "-" before "dri" and find out those records which ends with "dri"

Comment: And when `dri` isn't the last value, such as `P1933; battery dri-pu-103/2` and `P49384; Open vehicle bonnet-BO-dri 22/10`, @AmmadHadiEhsan ? This handles 1 scenario of 4.